# sed trying to replace string with another string

Tags: regex, bash, sed

i have the following regex command in my bash script:

```
 sed -i -e 's/\(expose_php = On\)/\1expose_php = Off/' /etc/php/php.ini
```

Instead of replacing:

```
  expose_php = On
```

with

```
expose_php = Off
```

it's doing the following:

```
 expose_php = Onexpose_php = Off
```

This is my first crack at bash and sed...
any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: You are catching `expose_php = On` and then printing back with `\1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
sed -i -e 's/expose_php = On/expose_php = Off/' /etc/php/php.ini
```

No need to capture the match and use back reference `\1` in replacement in your case.